# How to display an image from a path in asp.net MVC 4 and Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, razor

I have the following model:

```
public class Player
{


    public String ImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return "~/Content/img/sql_error.JPG";
        }

    }
```

And, this is my `.cshtml` file:

```
@model SoulMasters.Models.Game.Player

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Game";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GameLayout.cshtml";
var imagePath = @Model.ImagePath;
}

<fieldset>
<legend>Player</legend>

   <div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImagePath)
</div>
@imagePath
<div style="padding:10px;">

    <img src=@imagePath alt="Sample Image" width="300px" />

    <img  alt="asd" >
        model.ImagePath;
    </img>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

The result is simple text:

```
~/Content/img/sql_error.JPG
~/Content/img/sql_error.JPG
Sample Image asd model.ImagePath;
```

Also, I have tried the following line, and it works:

```
<img src="~/Content/img/sql_error.JPG" alt="Sample Image" width="300px" />
```

How to display that image from path?
Could the image path be different based on settings? Any other ideas?

I don't really get it now on how razor syntax works.

Comment: try this `<img src="@Url.Content(@item.ImagePath)"  />`

Comment: You Can follow this example:
http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-an-image-from-a-path-in-asp-net-MVC-and-Razor-view

Answer (score 144, accepted):

In your View try like this

```
  <img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: hi, i am saving Imagepath in database as : `c://user/tom/images` ,  i am not able to retrieve it in view why ?

Comment: Thank U so mush for your answer :)

Comment: sometimes these one liners are helpful! :)

Answer (score 10):

you can also try with this answer :

```
 <img src="~/Content/img/@Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.ImagePath)" style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this ,

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Sample Image" style="height:50px;width:100px;"/>

(or)

<img src="~/Content/img/@Url.Content(model =>model.ImagePath)" style="height:50px;width:100px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
      <img src="~/Images/@m.Url" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width:200px; height:200px;" />
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post code dumps, rather, explain why this code solves the problem.