# How to display an image from path in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Before starting, I've seen this asked here before and I've followed the answer and examples given here:

[how to display image from path in asp.net mvc 4 and razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986980/how-to-display-image-from-path-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-razor-view)

But when i do

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" class="dker" alt="..." />
```

I get an error

> Source Error
>
> ```
>    [No relevant source lines]
>    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
> ```

In my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace NSProfileImages
{
    public class ProfileImages
    {
        public string ImagePath
        {
            get
            {
                return "~/Assets/Images/user_images/avatars/123@123.com.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model NSProfileImages.ProfileImages

<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" class="dker" alt="..." />
```

If I do

```
<img src="~/Assets/Images/user_images/avatars/123@123.com.jpg" class="dker" alt="..." />
```

it will display the image normally and no errors.

Comment: Do you actually pass an instance of the model to the view in your controller?

Comment: Which object is `null`?  How are you providing the model to the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* that you forgot to supply an instance of the model to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // here we instantiate the type and supply it to the view. 
    ViewData.Model = new ProfileImages();
    return View();
}
```

Alternatively, you could supply the model instance via the `View` method like so:

```
 return View(new ProfileImages());
```

---

Note that in this case you could very well make the model property `static` which will remove the need to supply the view model altogether:

```
public class ProfileImages {
    public static string ImagePath {
        get {
            return "~/Assets/Images/user_images/avatars/123@123.com.jpg";
        }
    }
}
...
<img src="@Url.Content(NsProfileImages.ProfileImages.ImagePath)" 
     class="dker" alt="..." />
```

Comment: Hi, all the methods you shared did work, thank you. Now what would you recommend is the better way to do this?

Comment: @Johhan It depends really. But generally the first approach will be more flexible. Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should have something like this:

```
 ActionResult Index(){
 return View(new ProfileImages());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not passing model to view:

```
var model = new ProfileImages();
return View(model);
```

Comment: that did it, now I'm wondering, do I need to do the same for every view?

Comment: No. For posts, the model received will be automatically passed if none is specified.

Comment: But in your case, as the field is read-only, the value needs to be in a hiddenfield to kept between posts.