# View an image in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can view an image in index file like this :

```
    @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)*@//Instead of this, I use the line below
    <img src="~/Images/@item.ImagePath" height=100 width=200>
```

But In details file I have this :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImagePath)
```

How can I view the image in details file when there is a **model** not **item**? I have done several attempts but failed all of them. Thanks.

Comment: what is the text coming ``Model.ImagePath``?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986980/how-to-display-image-from-path-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-razor-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom template and dataannotations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450(v=VS.100).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application

Comment: Thank you but how do those links answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be like :

```
<img src="~/Images/@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" height=100 width=200 />
```

Answer (score 0):

This razortag string " @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImagePath) " is calling the DB, getting the path and then presenting the path string as its output. In the Index view " item.ImagePath " is a variable that has been populated and currently contains the path ready for output. In the Details view, there are no variables, and the ImagePath is empty because the function has not run. Well technically it ran once but since it delivered its output to the view it is again empty by the time you try to use it. To get the ImagePath as your img src call the whole function where you are placing the image and it will run again and its output will be the ImagePath used for the img src.

This also will work in the Index view as well. The codeproject.com link in the above answer provides some relevant ideas.

```
"<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImagePath)"
```