# Display Image from Path in Asp.Net Core and Razor view?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to display a picture of an item in MVC View Razor webpage.

The following was not working.
ImageLocation only has picture number filename.

```
Example: 
Product1.jpg
Product2.jpg
Product3.jpg
Product4.jpg
```

View was not working, just need to display one product image:

```
@model ElectronicsStore.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            <img src="~/images/@Url.Content(Model.ImageLocation)" alt="Image">
        </dt>
        <dd>

        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

this solution did not work yet, as it using previous version of mvc net
[How to display an image from a path in asp.net MVC 4 and Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986980/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-path-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-razor-view)

Comment: A simple technique to check the path is, once the page is rendered look at the html generated for the img tags.

Comment: Do you put your images folder in` wwwroot` and have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in startup? Press `F12` to check whether you have the element like `<img src="/images/Product1.jpg" alt="Image">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to get all images in the directory. Of course you can tweak it for your needs.

I used something like this:

```
var images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("Path"))
                             .Select(fn => "Path" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
```

and to display it I would use:

```
foreach (var image in (IEnumerable<string>)images)
{
      //Your logic here eg:
      <img class="img" src="@Url.Content(image)" />
}
```

Tweak it for your needs

Comment: I just need to display one product image, will check if this works