# how to pass variable inside img src in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to pass variable which is a model property. variable is "@Model.DeviceImei". how to concatinate .jpeg ? so that i can dynamic image file names with .jpeg

code

```
 <img src="..\img\Transformers\@Model.DeviceImei.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="Transformer Image" />
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error with the code as it is now?

Comment: try looking at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986980/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-path-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-razor-view
You need to simply use `src="\img\@Model.ImageName"+".jpeg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simple solution would be

```
 <img src="..\img\Transformers\@(Model.DeviceImei + ".jpeg")" class="img-responsive" alt="Transformer Image" />
```